# Best way to assign variable names to values from a parameter file in R?

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I have an R program with a large and growing parameter file. Currently, I read the file values and manually assign them to variables names used in the program. This is unwieldy especially when I want to add a new item in the parameter list.

For example, I can use the toy file stored in cvs or text format,

```
## test using comments and blank lines
3     #an integer
TRUE  # a logical
5.3     #numeric

# and here is some
# commentary ...
2014-6-5   # a date
7.8     #strange here
some text  #text here
```

and use something like this to read back the file,

```
some.lst <- scan("Data/TestReadData.txt", what = character(),
sep = "\n", comment.char = "#", 
strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
```

This will result in a list of values of mode “text". I then proceed to assign these to variable values like so:

```
first.int <- as.integer(some.ls[1])
my.switch <- as.logical(some.ls[2])
parm1 <- as.numeric(some.ls[3])
the.date <- as.Date(some.ls[4])
nxt.val <- as.numeric(some.ls[5])
my.text <- some.ls[6]
```

But, I have 40 of these, and now I want to add a new parameter in the list below, say, below the 5.3 value in the example given. I have to go in and add the new value into the parameter file but also add a new variable into the variable assignment list and reshuffle all of the indices of the assignments.

Surely, there is a better way to do this, but I can’t think of anything. Ideas much appreciated.

Comment: What does `TestReadData.txt` look like? If it's no sensitive info, maybe you can edit your post and add it (or a sample). Is `some.lst` = `some.ls`?

Comment: Apparently, you know the correspondence from numbers (1 to 6 here) to classes and destination variable names...? Store that information in a data.frame or similar and then iterate over the rows using `assign(myname[i],as(some.ls[i],myclass[i]))`

Comment: May be you need `lapply` or `mapply`. A reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't keep all these in a .r file that collects them all in a named list which you then simply `source()`. Then the types will all be right.

Comment: Yeah, I guess joran is right. Assigning 40 diversely-named parameters into the global environment will just give you a headache down the road relative to having them stored in some parameter `list`.

Comment: Holy cow, I knew the answer was starring me in the face. Store the whole thing in an R source file is the obvious answer. Then, I edit assignment and value all at the same time. This might not work if I had different scripts with a different set of variable names accessing the same data file, but I don’t. Thanks Joran. Perfect answer! Dumb question, it turns out. @lukeA The file looks exactly like what I posted in the question.

Comment: @Ernie: Pardon me, there's whisky in the jar... :-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have some stuff, all coerced to character when it was read into R:

```
some_stuff <- c("11","TRUE","1.2")
```

First, write down how you want each thing dealt with:

```
cleanem <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
i   nm          type      
1   first.int   integer
2   my.switch   logical
3   parm1       numeric
",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then deal with them, storing the result in a list:

```
res <- with(cleanem,setNames(mapply(as,some_stuff,type,SIMPLIFY=FALSE),nm))
# $first.int
# [1] 11

# $my.switch
# [1] TRUE

# $parm1
# [1] 1.2
```

Comment: Frank, an elegant answer. Another solution with lots of flexibility. Thanks.